# PyAudio installation error in python windows

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

Please check the screenshot below. when I installed PyAudio in python3.7.0 with pip 19.3 below error comes. And also unable to install in pycharm IDE.

python 3.7.0 32 bits, pip 19.3

```sh
""C:\Users\Bhiba Kumari\PycharmProjects\mozilla\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\BHIBAK~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bwt0kpug
\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\BHIBAK~1\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-record-ti2oers0\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\Bhiba Kumari\PycharmProjects\mozilla\venv\include\site\python
3.7\PyAudio"" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\BHIBAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bwt0kpug\PyAudio\
```

I also tried with .whl file no use.

[image: error]

Comment: You need to format your question properly, see [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

use this to install pyaudio:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

> *Note-1: pyaudio has a dependency of portaudio which you need to install before install pyaudio. Install portaudio in windows is a bit of headache for amatures(BTW this has not much to do with your skill). So the above method.*